# Import lucasr twowayview

Tags: android-studio, import, module

I'm stuck while importing [twowayview](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) as module to my project.

[image].

Next button is not getting enabled, is it the correct way to do it, or there is another way.

please help.

Comment: You can use a gradle dependency insted of importing the code locally

Comment: just adding gradle dependency would work??

Answer (score 0):

I guess wanting to import the library TwoWayView is because you want to create lists and horizontal and vertical grids. If so I recommend you use the called RecyclerView, that can do everything you do with TwoWayView, i.e. can create lists and grids in horizontally and vertically.

Here you can get information about RecyclerView use in horizontal and vertical:

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Also I have to say I had some bugs with the code shown on the page AndroidHive.

It turns out that in the `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity.java` the method that is called `prepareMovieData()` is declared in last place, when it should be called right after declaring RecyclerView, ie, right after this line:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

If this call is declared it in last place, a mistake appear that the object that we created (in the case of AndroidHive is the `Movies` class) will appear this to `null`, ie, it has no data.

Moreover, at the end of `prepareMovieData()` method the following line states:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For me personally, this line failure in the application that causes the App is closed, eliminating this code works perfectly provoked me. Actually, not that it serves this line, but I would appreciate if anyone knows why, to edit this entry explaining it.

Finally, if the intent of this post was to create a RecyclerView horizontally, then I leave the explanation for a RecyclerView is horizontal or vertical.

In the `onCreate()` method of file `MainActivity.java` we add a LayoutManager to RecyclerView with the following lines:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

This Layout Manager is responsible to tell the RecyclerView as the data that we introduce will be displayed, ie, if the content is vertically, horizontally, in a list, etc .. So if our list is displayed **horizontally** only we need to edit the above lines by the following:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

If you want the list **vertically**, we leave the lines as they are.

Hope this can help you.